# how to convert values of identical keys to list

Tags: python, key-value

unfortunately i have a big dictionary having many identical keys in it, and python not allows identical keys and prints only the last occurrence, now the solution i found is to changes values of identical keys to list or tuple.but i am not able to find a automatic way to do so.also i want to remain the order of values in list as i tried to mention it in example dictionary below.
my current dictionary looks like this:

```
dic = {
'a' : 2,
'a' : 1,
'b' : 2,
'a' : 4,
'a' : 3,
'b' : 1,
'b' : 2,
'c': 1
  }
```

now according to solution it should be converted to like this:

```
dic = {
'a' : [2,1,4,3],
'b' : [2,1,2],
'c': 1
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dictionary cannot have identical keys. Even if you define them in a dict literal, only one of each will be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first probe whether the dictionary already contains the key for which you're attempting to add a new value. Once you've determined if the key already exists, you can then check whether the returned value is a single number, or a list of numbers and act accordingly.

In pseudocode:

```
# Get current value associated with new key in dict.
# If returned value is None, add new value for key in question.
# Else If returned value is a list, append new value to list, store list for key in question
# Else, returned value was a single number; create a list of returned value and new value. Store list for key in question.
```

A solution in Python:

```
class DictUtil(object):
    """ A utility class that automates handling of key collisions for a dictionary object. """

    @staticmethod
    def add_to_dict(dict, new_key, new_value):
        # Get whatever currently exists within the dictionary for the given key.
        value_in_dict = dict.get(new_key)

        # If the value for the given key is None, there is no current entry, so we can add the new value.
        if value_in_dict is None:
            dict[new_key] =  new_value

        # If the value for a given key returned a list, append new value to list and re-store in dict.
        elif type(value_in_dict) in [list, tuple]:
            dict[new_key].append(new_value)

        # Otherwise, the get returned a single item. Make a list of the returned value and the new value and re-store.
        else:
            dict[new_key] = [value_in_dict, new_value]

def main():
    """ Entry point for an example script to demonstrate Dictutil functionality. """
    dict = {}

    # Populating values in dict using Dictutil method: add_to_dict:
    DictUtil.add_to_dict(dict, 'a', 2)
    DictUtil.add_to_dict(dict, 'a', 1)
    DictUtil.add_to_dict(dict, 'b', 2)
    DictUtil.add_to_dict(dict, 'a', 4)
    DictUtil.add_to_dict(dict, 'a', 3)
    DictUtil. add_to_dict(dict, 'b', 1)
    DictUtil.add_to_dict(dict, 'b', 2)
    DictUtil.add_to_dict(dict, 'c', 1)

    # Printing dictionary contents
    for key, value in dict.iteritems():
        print 'Key: %s \t Value: %s' % (key, value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your reply, your code doing the same thing which is required to me, earlier when i was given minus one on my question i became hopeless but your answer gave me a new hope, and now i am looking deeply your solution and code and trying to understand it because i am new to programming and python 3. currently there is next question for me, what should i do to convert my dictionary ? where should i place it in this code and in which format ? Once again thanks a lot for your time and help , it saved me a lot. Regards.

Comment: So in the function defined as `main()`, there is an empty dict defined `dict = {}`. That is the dictionary that would be used/populated with key-value pairs.

I wrote *DictUtil* as a class, but realistically you could just take the method `add_to_dict(dict, new_key, new_value)` and place it into your code. The only thing is that you will need to call `add_to_dict()` each time you want to add to the dictionary, instead of doing `dict['a'] = 2`, etc...